# Cythonizing sklearn/_isotonic.pyx failed

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to install the OCRF-Examples (https://github.com/ngoix/OCRF).

The installation instructions said:

```
conda create -n OCRF_env python=2.7 anaconda
source activate OCRF_env
conda install -n OCRF_env numpy scipy cython matplotlib
git clone https://github.com/ngoix/OCRF
cd OCRF
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pyper
python setup.py install
```

I was able to run all the commands of the installation instructions without any problems - except for the last one:

```
python setup.py install
```

Here I got this error:

[image: Error]

Cython is installed with the latest version (0.29.13) and no other Cython versions are installed.

If relevant: I already had Python 3.6.9 installed on my Macbook. Due to the OCRF installation, I now have Python 2.7. as additional environment.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like OCRF has been updated for 3 years - it comes bundled with a version of sklearn from that era too. I suspect you'd be best off finding a version of Cython from that time.

Comment: With that said - a closer look at the error (which would be much better as text rather than an image!) suggests that Cython is failing to import and it hasn't even got as far as looking at OCRF...

Comment: Changing the Cython version to 0.27.3 has helped! Many thanks!
I came across further problems after that, but one can solve them with https://github.com/ngoix/OCRF/issues/7 and https://github.com/ngoix/OCRF/issues/9.